# AVPlayerViewController show black screen some times

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I create an player and working fine in most part of times.

In some situations (that I didn't realized why) screen video stays black with a play button that does nothing.

I verified url and is ok, that's not the problem.

In my viewController I can call this block of code multiples times with different urls, that's why I 'restart' AVPlayerViewController.

```
    // Create an var in class...

    // ....

    self.videoPlayerViewController?.player?.pause()
    self.videoPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    self.videoPlayerViewController?.player = viewModel.avPlayer

    if let avController = self.videoPlayerViewController {
        self.add(avController, in: self.playerView)
        avController.player?.play()
    } else {
        // Error
    }
```

That's function add:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func add(_ viewController: UIViewController, in view: UIView) {
        viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
        addChildViewController(viewController)
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        view.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Someone knows what is wrong?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After so many time.. I found solution.

The problem was that I wasn't cleaning AVPlayer inside AVPlayerController. And I also added New instance inside a DispachQueue.

That's new code:

```
self.videoPlayerViewController?.player?.pause()
self.videoPlayerViewController?.player = nil
self.videoPlayerViewController = nil
self.videoPlayerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
self.videoPlayerViewController?.player = viewModel.avPlayer
```

And after I added in viewController:

```
if let avController = self.videoPlayerViewController {
     DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
         if let strongSelf = self {
             strongSelf.add(avController, in: strongSelf.playerView)
             avController.player?.play()
         }
     }
} else {
    // Error
}
```

I hope it could help someone!!

Comment: Hi Rafaela Lourenço,

I am facing the same issue with my messaging app. I have a video cell in tableview. First Time I select the video from gallery, by clicking send its working fine. But when I close the app kill it and reopen it the video is not showing and its blank.

And strange thing is if I select another video and send in chat then all other videos start appearing.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I can provide the code as well if you want.